Floating button with a menu
I have tried to implement a floating button and when you click the button a menu should pop up, but I cannot figured out how to place the menu properly. I place the menu in the same position as the button, but what I want is to place the menu relatively in the center of the screen. I want the same behavior as the assistive native button plus the menu. Right now I have the button behavior but I struggle a lot with menu behavior.
This is what I got so fare.
This is the button:
    struct AssistiveFloatingButton: View {
    @State var opacityState: Double = 1
    @Binding var buttonPosition: CGPoint
    var action : () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                        .shadow(radius: 3)
                        .overlay {
                            Image(systemName: "message.badge.filled.fill")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                        }
                        .opacity(opacityState)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            action()
                            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.1)) {
                                opacityState = 0.2
                            }

                            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.1).delay(0.1)) {
                                opacityState = 1
                            }
                        }
                        .position(buttonPosition)
                        .gesture(
                            DragGesture()
                                .onChanged { self.buttonPosition = $0.location }
                                .onEnded { value in

                                    var currentPostion = value.location

                                    if currentPostion.x > (geometry.size.width/2) {
                                        currentPostion.x = geometry.size.width-34
                                    } else {
                                        currentPostion.x =  16
                                    }

                                    withAnimation(.interpolatingSpring(mass: 1.0, stiffness: 100.0, damping: 10, initialVelocity: 0)) {
                                        buttonPosition = currentPostion
                                    }
                                }
                        )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

And this is the view with the menu ande button:
struct MainView: View {
    @State var isShowing  = false
    @State private var menuScale: CGFloat = 0.1
    @State private var menuOpacity: Double = 0
    @State private var buttonPosition: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if isShowing {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(1..<4) { _ in
                        Text("something")
                    }
                    .frame(width: 150)
                    .padding()
                    .background(.white)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16))
                }
                .scaleEffect(menuScale, anchor: .center)
                .opacity(menuOpacity)
                .position(buttonPosition)
                .animation(.spring(), value: isShowing)
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    withAnimation(.spring()) {
                        menuScale = 1.0
                        menuOpacity = 1.0
                    }
                })
                .onDisappear(perform: {
                    withAnimation(.spring()) {
                        menuScale = 1.0
                        menuOpacity = 1.0
                    }
                })
            }

            AssistiveFloatingButton(buttonPosition: $buttonPosition) {
                withAnimation {
                    self.isShowing.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
        .background(.black)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

And this is how it looks like:



I believe I understand your question. Please correct me if I have misunderstood.
Just adjust the position of the VStack. Check out the code where I changed the X Position of the VStack and managed the left and right side floating positions as well.
struct AssistiveFloatingButton: View {
    @State var opacityState: Double = 1
    @Binding var buttonPosition: CGPoint
    var action: () -> Void
    var isFloatingAlignmentLeft: (Bool) -> Void

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                        .shadow(radius: 3)
                        .overlay {
                            Image(systemName: "message.badge.filled.fill")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                        }
                        .opacity(opacityState)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            action()
                            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.1)) {
                                opacityState = 0.2
                            }

                            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.1).delay(0.1)) {
                                opacityState = 1
                            }
                        }
                        .position(buttonPosition)
                        .gesture(
                            DragGesture()
                                .onChanged { self.buttonPosition = $0.location }
                                .onEnded { value in

                                    var currentPostion = value.location

                                    if currentPostion.x > (geometry.size.width / 2) {
                                        currentPostion.x = geometry.size.width - 34
                                        isFloatingAlignmentLeft(false)
                                    } else {
                                        currentPostion.x = 16
                                        isFloatingAlignmentLeft(true)
                                    }

                                    withAnimation(.interpolatingSpring(mass: 1.0, stiffness: 100.0, damping: 10, initialVelocity: 0)) {
                                        buttonPosition = currentPostion
                                    }
                                }
                        )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    @State var isShowing = false
    @State var isFloatingAlignmentLeft = false
    @State private var menuScale: CGFloat = 0.1
    @State private var menuOpacity: Double = 0
    @State private var buttonPosition: CGPoint = .init(x: 100, y: 100)

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if isShowing {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(1 ..< 4) { _ in
                        Text("something")
                    }
                    .frame(width: 150)
                    .padding()
                    .background(.white)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16))
                }
                .scaleEffect(menuScale, anchor: .center)
                .opacity(menuOpacity)
                .position(x: isFloatingAlignmentLeft ? buttonPosition.x + 140 : buttonPosition.x - 120, y: buttonPosition.y)   //  Hang it here according to your needs.
                .animation(.spring(), value: isShowing)
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    withAnimation(.spring()) {
                        menuScale = 1.0
                        menuOpacity = 1.0
                    }
                })
                .onDisappear(perform: {
                    withAnimation(.spring()) {
                        menuScale = 1.0
                        menuOpacity = 1.0
                    }
                })
            }

            AssistiveFloatingButton(buttonPosition: $buttonPosition) {
                withAnimation {
                    self.isShowing.toggle()
                }
            } isFloatingAlignmentLeft: { isAlignment in
                isFloatingAlignmentLeft = isAlignment
            }
        }
        .background(.black)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

Check the output screenshot.


Exactly what I want, is it possible to have the position of the menu dynamic, so I don't have move the menu with a constant of like 140 but instead doing it relative to the screen edge?
